# How to store state in an Actor

Tags: asynchronous, graph, akka, state

I am using the AKKA framework for concurrency with Java and have the following use case

The actors operate on a graph data structure and work on each node in the graph in a specific order and do not proceed to the next until a node is processed

Here is the relevant code

```
GraphProcessor:
if (msg instanceof processGraph) {

      // For each level in the graph create a child at each level, for nodes on the same level create child actors simultaneously

      BreadthFirstIterator bfs = new BreadthFirstIterator<>(graph);
        while (bfs.hasNext()) {
          ActorRef NodeProcesor = getContext().actorOf(NodeProcesor.props());
             NodeProcesor.tell(send the node),
                       getSelf());

     }

    }
  }
```

Now the question is,  while the nodes of one graph are getting processed a new graph may be handed over to the GraphProcessor, this will confuse the actor from tracking the state of the graph? How do I correctly maintain this informtaion?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Correct pattern for accumulating state in an Akka actor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24708096/correct-pattern-for-accumulating-state-in-an-akka-actor)

Comment: Yes, an example in Java is what I was looking for,

Comment: I think it should not be hard to convert Scala code into java

Comment: I dont understand Scala and it is difficult to understand a problem when I am unsure of what the solution is. The link also seems to solve a different problem than what I am looking for, again I might be wronly interpreting a language I do no completely understand

Comment: See you want to store the state of an actor, so the basics says you must have done it in the Prestop phase of an actor now it doesn’t matter in what language you are going to implement it.

Comment: I am not arguing on what language it shoud be implemnted in, I am trying to say I dont understand Scala so its hard to understand the linked solution, please reply if you can explain your solution with an example in Java

Comment: I am not arguing I am just saying, and sorry i know Scala and as Akka is written in Scala it has better collaboration with Akka so I will suggest better to use Scala.